# Add a multivariate linear regression line on a ggplot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, lm

I have created a scatter plot of the variables Y and X1 using ggplot.
I would like to add the following linear regression line to the ggplot:

```
model <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, dataframe)

ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = X1, y = Y, col = X5)) +
  geom_point()
```

X5 is a dummy variable. I would like to add the linear regression line of X1 when all other variables are held constant

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

This really requires some sample data to demonstrate. Ideally sample data should be given in the question, but I'll create some here:

```r
set.seed(1)

dataframe <- data.frame(X1 = sample(100, 30),
                        X2 = sample(100, 30),
                        X3 = sample(100, 30),
                        X4 = sample(100, 30),
                        X5 = factor(rep(c("a", "b"), each = 15)))

dataframe <- within(dataframe, Y <- 1 * X1 + 
                               0.2 * X2 + 
                               2 * X3 + 
                               0.05 * X4 + 
                               5 * as.numeric(X5) +
                               rnorm(30, 0, 4))
```

This allows us to create a model like so:

```
model <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, dataframe)
```

Which looks like this:

```
summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, data = dataframe)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -5.2357 -1.5556  0.0027  0.9677  7.1806 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  7.65038    2.35052   3.255 0.003363 ** 
#> X1           0.98973    0.02227  44.437  < 2e-16 ***
#> X2           0.16057    0.02035   7.890 4.03e-08 ***
#> X3           2.01153    0.02350  85.609  < 2e-16 ***
#> X4           0.03415    0.02448   1.395 0.175828    
#> X5b          5.06526    1.21321   4.175 0.000338 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.172 on 24 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9972, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9966 
#> F-statistic:  1717 on 5 and 24 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If you want to plot predicted y values at a range of `X1` values while holding the other variables constant, you can simply create a new data frame with the `X1` range, and the other variables at their desired level (here, just their mean), and run it through `predict`.

```
new_df <- with(dataframe,
               data.frame(X1 = rep(seq(min(X1), max(X1), length.out = 100), 2),
                          X2 = mean(X2),
                          X3 = mean(X3),
                          X4 = mean(X4),
                          X5 = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 100)))
  
new_df$Y <- predict(model, new_df)
```

Now we simply plot a `geom_line` with predicted values:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = X1, y = Y, col = X5)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = new_df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! what does the 100 and 2 refer to ```length.out = 100), 2```

Answer (score 0):

@AllanCameron's answer is fine. There are a few packages that facilitate the second part (`effects`, `emmeans`, `ggeffects`).

Following from the example given:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)
new_df <- emmeans(model, spec = ~X1*X5,
    at = list(X1 = seq(min(dataframe$X1), max(dataframe$X1), length.out = 100)))
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = X1, y = Y, col = X5)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(new_df), aes(y = emmean))
```

The `seq()` stuff in the `emmeans()` call there is to specify what values of `X1` we want predictions for (by default, `emmeans()` will give us predicted values only at the *mean* value of `X1`).  `length.out = 100` is actually overkill for this case (`length.out = 2` would actually work fine since the predictions are straight lines), but is harmless and will generalize to cases such as GLMs or nonlinear models where the predictions are not straight lines.

With a little more work, these packages will also give you confidence intervals on the predictions, which you can plot with `geom_ribbon()`.