# How do I write a linear model with multiple variables using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, lm, interaction

Imagine if my linear regression model was: lm(y~x + N * P) -> (the multiplication is for an interaction)

How would I plot this using ggplot? That all variables are used in the linear regression model.
Do I need to use geom_smooth? eventhough the formula in geom_smooth is formula = y~x? does this include the extra variables plus interaction?

I tried:

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = N) + 
geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y~x', fullrange = TRUE)
```

But I have a feeling it does not add all the variables in my ggplot.

Comment: To plot regression models with multiple variables I would suggest to estimate you model outside of `ggplot` and afterwards plot the results via a `geom_line`, i.e. multiple lines for each or for your desired levels of the interaction terms. See e.g. [Add a multivariate linear regression line on a ggplot using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292705/add-a-multivariate-linear-regression-line-on-a-ggplot-using-r) for an example of this approach.

Comment: The formula`y ~ x` finds the best fitting line on a plot of y against x, ignoring your other two variables. If we add a second independent variable by using the formula `y ~ x + N` then conceptually we are finding the best fitting _plane_ through a cloud of points in a 3D space with y, x and N on 3 orthogonal axes. This would have to be shown as a 3D plot, or as several lines that are "slices" through this plane. The formula `y ~ x + N * P` represents the best fitting 3D space through a 4D point cloud and is very hard to represent on a 2D plot, though using 2 faceting dimensions _might_ work

Comment: Without seeing your data or understanding what you are trying to illustrate with your plot, we can't really give you any more definite advice. Perhaps you could edit your question to include reproducible data? Thanks.

Comment: I think this should probably be closed as a duplicate of the Q linked by @stefan, but maybe the OP could confirm ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.